# How to make a discord bot do something after I react to an emoji in an image sent by itself

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making my first discord bot and I'm trying to make it send a message after I react to one of its emojis, problem is, when I click the thumbs up emoji, the bot simply does not send the message, it's been a few hours now and I can't find the problem, I'm sorry if this has been solved somewhere else, I couldn't find anything that works.

```
if (command === "ping") {

    const attachment = new MessageAttachment('https://cdn.mcr.ea.com/3/images/ac394369-2801-4e09-87eb-82ca54e26254/1588018258-0x0-0-0.jpg'); 
    const sentMessage = await message.channel.send({files: [attachment] })
    sentMessage.react('');
    //sentMessage.react('');
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
    };
    const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        message.channel.send(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        message.channel.send(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });
```

**EDIT**

I found that I was missing the `"GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"` intent, now i have these 3 `"GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"`, still not working sadly!

Here's the full code:
https://pastebin.com/Q0eZ6VSz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hi, this code is working except a small thing...

```js
sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
```

change this to:

```js
sentMessage.createReactionCollector({filter, time: 15000 });
```

also I suggest you to add `max: 1` option too.

so final code:

```js
...
sentMessage.createReactionCollector({filter, max: 1,  time: 15000 });
```

in this situation only gets first react by you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The time part now works, sadly It doesn't react when I click on the emoji, I'm using the final code you provided, it ends up saying "Collected 0 items", both in the console and in Discord, I tried with different emojis and I get the same problem.

Comment: Can you please share your last code with editing main post?

Comment: I added a pastebin with the full code, thanks for the help again.

Comment: This error because of you didn't add `return` to beginning of the filter statement. Add it, it solves your problem.

Comment: Could you point me to the part of the code? Can't seem to fix it

Comment: Thanks for submitting it as answer. Enjoy on your works!

Comment: const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        `return` reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
    };